# Can API Return Reverse Results?

Tags: api

I am using the CustomValues Get API I would like to have the most recent entries listed first.

Is there a way that I can sort results in reverse when placing an API get?

For example, below I want to sort the values['217'] so that values['217']['10'] is the first. Here are the results I get:

```
{
"is_error": 0,
"version": 3,
"count": 1,
"id": 217,
"values": {
    "217": {
        "entity_id": "7088",
        "latest": "2016-11-01 00:00:00",
        "id": "217",
        "1": "2016-10-25 00:00:00",
        "2": "2016-10-18 00:00:00",
        "3": "2016-01-01 00:00:00",
        "4": "2016-01-01 00:00:00",
        "5": "2016-01-01 00:00:00",
        "6": "2016-10-27 00:00:00",
        "7": "2016-10-27 00:00:00",
        "8": "2016-10-27 00:00:00",
        "9": "2016-10-27 00:00:00",
        "10": "2016-10-27 00:00:00",
    }
}
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can, though it's not well-documented!

I recalled that there was some sort of "sort" option, which I confirmed by checked the [Using the API](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Using+the+API) documentation.  However, the documentation is incomplete (I'll fix that in a minute).

Fortunately, I found [the code that handles this](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/api/v3/utils.php#L833), and saw that you can sort by various field options.  See my screenshot below; I also confirmed that sorting by `last_name desc` also works.  You should be able to sort by any field.

[image]

Comment: This is great. Thanks for finding this information. Unfortunately for my case the sorting needs to be for the results of a field that has multiple values. I don't think I can sort those values. I have updated my original question with the results that I currently get.

Answer (score 0):

Per your comment, I see you want to know about reversing the order of *multi-value custom fields*.  I don't think you can flip the return array directly.  But if you're consuming it in PHP/JS/etc., you can iterate through the loop backwards.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777597/reverse-order-of-foreach-list-items for a PHP example.